# Connection between Amazon Workspaces instances

Tags: amazon-workspaces

I'm having hard time to make Amazon Workspaces multiple instances to connect other.

Here is the detail. I created 2 workspaces, say instance A and instance B.
I just want to make sure if I can ping from A to B, but no luck.
Why can't I do such a very simple thing? Is there any configurations needed other than disabling firewall on the B?

Could you please, help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

As every resource within a AWS VPC, WorkSpaces use security groups that are attached to the network interface. By default there are no inbound connections allowed at the security groups attached to a WorkSpaces, connectivity between resources without opening anything will never work.

You can add a security group with inbound rules to your WorkSpaces, but be careful with that! (look at the directory config which it is).

From: [Security groups for your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)

> A security group acts as a virtual firewall for your instance to control inbound and outbound traffic.

> When you create a new security group, it has no inbound rules.
> Therefore, no inbound traffic originating from another host to your
> instance is allowed until you add inbound rules to the security group.

From: [Security Groups for Your WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces-security-groups.html)

> You can add a default WorkSpaces security group to a directory. After you associate a new security group with a WorkSpaces directory, new WorkSpaces that you launch or existing WorkSpaces that you rebuild will have the new security group.
> You can also add this new default security group to existing WorkSpaces without rebuilding them, as explained later in this topic.